# Ajax отправка нескольких форм

Tags: ajax

Вот пример , отправляет только 1 форму.
А как доделать скрипт так , чтобы он мог отправить 2ю , 3ю и т.д. формы со своим другим id ?

```css
form {width:400px;margin:20px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>
$(function(){$('#forma1').on('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();var $that=$(this),fData=$that.serialize();$.ajax({url:$that.attr('action'),type:$that.attr('method'),data:{form_data:fData},dataType:'html',success:function(json){if(json){$that.replaceWith(json)}}})})});</script>

<script>
$(function(){$('#forma2').on('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();var $that=$(this),fData=$that.serialize();$.ajax({url:$that.attr('action'),type:$that.attr('method'),data:{form_data:fData},dataType:'html',success:function(json){if(json){$that.replaceWith(json)}}})})});</script>

<script>
$(function(){$('#forma3').on('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();var $that=$(this),fData=$that.serialize();$.ajax({url:$that.attr('action'),type:$that.attr('method'),data:{form_data:fData},dataType:'html',success:function(json){if(json){$that.replaceWith(json)}}})})});</script>

<div class="row">
<h3>Форма 1</h3>
<form action="forma/obrabotchik/sal.php" id="forma1" method="post" name="forma1">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" name="name_sal" placeholder="Как к вам обращаться ?" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" name="tel_sal" placeholder="Ваш контактный телефон:" required="" type="tel">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" name="komment_sal" placeholder="Ваш адрес или комментарий:" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" required=""> <a class="persona" href="#">Разрешаю обработку моих персональных данных</a>
</label>
</div>
<input class="submit btn btn-success btn-forma" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
</div>

<div class="row">
<h3>Форма 2</h3>
<form action="forma/obrabotchik/sal.php" id="forma2" method="post" name="forma2">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" name="name_sal" placeholder="Как к вам обращаться ?" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" name="tel_sal" placeholder="Ваш контактный телефон:" required="" type="tel">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" name="komment_sal" placeholder="Ваш адрес или комментарий:" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" required=""> <a class="persona" href="#">Разрешаю обработку моих персональных данных</a>
</label>
</div>
<input class="submit btn btn-success btn-forma" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
</div>

<div class="row">
<h3>Форма 3</h3>
<form action="forma/obrabotchik/sal.php" id="forma3" method="post" name="forma3">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" name="name_sal" placeholder="Как к вам обращаться ?" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" name="tel_sal" placeholder="Ваш контактный телефон:" required="" type="tel">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" name="komment_sal" placeholder="Ваш адрес или комментарий:" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" required=""> <a class="persona" href="#">Разрешаю обработку моих персональных данных</a>
</label>
</div>
<input class="submit btn btn-success btn-forma" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
</div>
```